# Reassign variable value as parameter

Tags: angular

I want to reassign a variable passing through multiple functions

```
public name: string;
public secondName: string;
public thirdName: string;

functionA(name: string) {
   this.functionB(name);
}

functionB(name: string) {
   name = "Hello World";
}
```

I would like to have my variables reassign to 'Hello World' when I call them in functionA() like this

```
functionA(this.name);
console.log(this.name);
```

What is wrong here ? Console.log outputs undefined. I know that "name" in functionB() doesn't directly references to this.name and that is the point of it, I would like to find a way for 'name' to references this.name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are passed by value, not by reference. When you pass `this.name` to functionB and functionB changes it, functionB is only changing the value of the argument.

To ensure it changes `this.name`, you can do something like:

```js
public name: string;

functionA() {
   this.functionB("hello world");
}

functionB(nameToSet: string) {
   this.name = nameToSet;
   console.log(nameToSet, this.name);
}
```

Article: https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c

Comment: That's kind of what I already have, but unfortunately I can't do it this way, as I have a lot of variables and that would mean create a function for each one of them. My goal is to assign any of them to 'Hello World' using just 2 generic functions !

Comment: Oh ok. Can you provide more details about the full use case? (to better understand it)

Comment: Your link actually solved my problem I guess: I only can modify the primary variable if it's an array or an object. As I'm passing texts, I just can give values to my function.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `this.name` instead of just `name`.
Your code would be like this:

```
  public name: string;


  functionA() {
      this.functionB(this.name);
   }

   functionB(name: string) {
      this.name = "Hello World";
      console.log('name', this.name);
   }
```

Look [there](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpxer3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a live demo

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the value of `this.name`. In your Class or Component you just declared the property "public name: string;" but didn't set it. So that property seems to be "undefined" => which is true in your example.

The local function variable **`name`** is of course set as a string "Hello World", which works.

If you want to set the `this.name` you need to set it in your `functionB` like:

```
functionB(name: string) {
   this.name = name;
   console.log(name, this.name);
}
```